# Check if documents exists in Firebase and return according icon

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, conditional-statements

I want to check if a specific document exists in a Firebase collection. According to that, my app should display a colored icon or a grey one. I'm trying to tackle the problem with a method, which returns a boolean. In my Build Widget, I call that method and assign the right icon.

Here is my method which checks if the document exists:

```
checkIfLikedOrNot(reference) async{
   DocumentSnapshot ds = await reference.collection("likes").document(currentUser.uid).get();
   print(ds.exists);
   return ds.exists;
}
```

The print shows the right values in the console, but my build widget seems to ignore the fact, that the boolean is true and always returns the icon which should be displayed if there is no document in the collection.

Here is the part of my Build Widget:

```
 GestureDetector(
      child: checkIfLikedOrNot(list[index].reference) == true

      ? 
         Icon(
          Icons.favorite,
          color: Colors.red,
         )
      : 
         Icon(
         FontAwesomeIcons.heart,
         color: null,
         ),
 )
```

Where is the problem with this statement? Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you can use an async function in a constructor like that?  Async functions don't return their final results immediately.

Comment: No, I am absolutely not sure :D Do you know how I could rewrite the function without async?

Comment: No, Firestore APIs are all async. You will have to wait for a query to complete before using the results.

Comment: How do I wait for the query? I thought await handles that....

Comment: Even though you have await in your function, your function still returns future, since it's marked as async. What I would do in this case is, call the function in init state, await it's result and set it to some variable in your state with setState. then use it in your ternary operator in gesture detector.

Comment: That was my first attempt. Unfortunately I try to build a list with multiple posts (like Instagram) so I can not use one state which would change according to each post...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on your usecase you can either use a [FutureBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html), or you keep it simple and create a variable to deal with the logic:

Inside your Widget:

```
bool isLiked = false;
```

Call your function from within initState():

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkIfLikedOrNot();
}
```

Change your logic to modify your variable and tell Flutter to rerender:

```
    checkIfLikedOrNot() async{
       DocumentSnapshot ds = await reference.collection("likes").document(currentUser.uid).get();
        this.setState(() {
          isLiked = ds.exists;
        });

    }
```

Draw the corresponding Icon:

```
Icon(isLiked?Icons.favorite:FontAwesomeIcons.heart,
     color: isLiked?Colors.red:null)
```

Edit: Since you are apparently dealing with a list of values, it makes sense to encapsulate them in an Object or use the FutureBuilder.

Comment: I tried it with Futurebuilder, but it seems that the Futurbuilder only fetches data once at the start. It does not rebuild. So when I click on the like button, the console registers the change, but I need to refresh the page to see the changes.

Comment: I removed the FutureBuilder and encapsulated the values in an own class. Now I work with setState and everything works fine. Not the cleanest solution, but it works.

Comment: This is the expected behaviour, since `.get()`, will always only get a snapshot once. If you want to listen for changes whenever they happen, you need a [StreamBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html). You can then set a stream to the snapshot of your likes and it will update and rebuild the view whenever there is an update in your Firestore.