# Check if field contains data in firebase using Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

[image]

Is there a method to find out if a document has values for a specific field? For example, I want to see if a document has a "socialMediaTag" field, which in this case does not exist. How can I do that using Flutter?

Comment: Hey my friend, did you get your answer?

Comment: I did not get an answer to this specific problem, but I did a workaround which involved assuming that these exist

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by using a boolean:

```
bool isLiked = false;
```

Change your logic to modify your variable and tell Flutter to rerender:

```
checkIfLikedOrNot() async{
   DocumentSnapshot ds = await reference.collection("likes").document(currentUser.uid).get();
    this.setState(() {
      isLiked = ds.exists;
    });

}
```

Call your function from within initState():

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkIfLikedOrNot();
}
```

For more info please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55879077/flutter-check-if-documents-exists-in-firebase-and-return-according-icon):

Comment: Note that, with `ds.exists`, you are not checking if the document has values for a specific field but **if the document exists**.

Comment: Ok sorry, you can just check it by this `firebseVal != null && firebaseVal != ""` condition