# Cloud Firestore Document Check after Phone Authentication

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I will try to explain it as clearly as possible

I wanted to add a check when verification is complete. In that the check is supposed to be like: Check if there is a document with document id as the user UID which has authenticated. If it is there then go to the home. If it is not there then create a document using updateData class that I have created already and then go to the home page

Here is my code for phone authentication

```
  Future phoneAuthentication(
    String fullName,
    String phoneNumber,
    String phoneIsoCode,
    String nonInternationalNumber,
    String profilePicture,
    String verificationCode,
    BuildContext context,
  ) async {
    _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
      timeout: Duration(seconds: 0),
      verificationCompleted: (AuthCredential authCredential) async {
        _auth.signInWithCredential(authCredential).then(
          (UserCredential result) async {
            User user = result.user;
            await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updateUserData(
              fullName,
              phoneNumber,
              phoneIsoCode,
              nonInternationalNumber,
              profilePicture,
            );
            Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => CustomerDashboard(),
              ),
              (route) => false,
            );
          },
        ).catchError(
          (e) {
            return null;
          },
        );
      },
      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException exception) {
        return "Error";
      },
      codeSent: (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) {
        var _credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
          verificationId: verificationId,
          smsCode: verificationCode,
        );
        _auth.signInWithCredential(_credential).then(
          (UserCredential result) async {
            User user = result.user;
            await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updateUserData(
              fullName,
              phoneNumber,
              phoneIsoCode,
              nonInternationalNumber,
              profilePicture,
            );
            Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => CustomerDashboard(),
              ),
              (route) => false,
            );
          },
        ).catchError(
          (e) {},
        );
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
        verificationId = verificationId;
      },
    );
  }
```

Please help me how I am supposed to add this check.

Comment: But you're already updating the document before checking whether there is a document.

Comment: @Apps247 Yeah so I need to add that check and that's what I need help with. Coz without that check the users document is always updating which I dont want. I want it to be updated if user document with user uid is not present else just return Home Screen so ya

Comment: Yeah, but your `updateUserData` is before your `// TODO`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied & adapted this code here from [this Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55879077/check-if-documents-exists-in-firebase-and-return-according-icon)

```
DocumentSnapshot ds = await YOUR_DB_REFERENCE_IDENTIFIER.collection("YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME").document(user.uid).get();
return ds.exists;
```